# Watershed analysis using GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, dem, contour, watershed

I have Contour lines shapefile which I imported that into GRASS and converted to a DEM using the IDW interpolation technique (r.surf.idw with npoints 250). Now I want watershed analysis to be done where I can get Flow accumulation, Flow direction, basin, Stream order, drainage pattern etc.

When I Try to run r.fill.dir after a while GRASS crashes and the process doesn't give any output. I have tried other hydrologic modelling under raster but it does the same.

Can anybody help me out with the procedure of doing this analysis in GRASS GIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.
 In what precise way were you "not that successful"?

Comment: Please read https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM for correct ways to generate a DEM from contour lines

Answer (score 2):

Instead of filling depression, you can use r.watershed command for your purpose.  you don't need to remove depression as post processing due to the module works with least-cost algorithm.
You can refer the manual with

```
g.manual r.watershed
```

or, https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.watershed.html.